# License for Vaadin Charts 2 not found. Go to vaadin.com/pro for more details

Tags: gwt, vaadin

I want to build an app with Vaadin with charts. Is there a (non-commercial) snap in replacement for the the Vaadin Charts 2, I'm specifically targeting to try https://github.com/vaadin/dashboard-demo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there does not exist a free replacement for the vaadin charts.
But vaadin charts is freely available for opensource projects.

On [this page](https://vaadin.com/pro-tools) in the bottom of the right column:

> **Non-commercial licenses**
>
> Free licenses are available for non-commercial
> users: projects for educational purposes in an university or a public
> school or similar; or projects for a non-profit organization.
> Non-commercial licenses are granted case by case upon request.

Otherwise you have to integrate another chart library,
like [highcharts](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/highchartsapi-add-on).